# The github action is passed but files are not posted to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, github-actions

I have a static web-site stored in AWS S3 and delivered with Cloudfront. I want to deploy updates to the bucket with the following github action .yaml file

```
name: Upload to S3

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '12.x'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: shallwefootball/s3-upload-action@master
        with:
          aws_key_id: ${{ secrets.AWS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
          aws_bucket: ${{ secrets.AWS_BUCKET }}
          source_dir: 'dist'
```

after the pr is created the jobs are passed but changes are not being pushed to S3
[image]

Comment: Please show the logs (text, no screenshot)

Comment: Ok i fixed it, had to specify the branch to push in the yaml file. Although I have another issue now and I'll need to post another question for that I guess.

Answer (score 0):

what if we include if:always() just after the name and the id as S3 ex: id: S3 just after uses: shallwefootball/s3-upload-action@master